# Add a Custom Send Button to Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-contextual-gadgets

Is it possible to add a custom send button to gmail?

I would like to add my own send button into Gmail, so that I can do
some additional checks as well as send the email.

Is it possible to do this?

Is there any sample code to do something very simple like alert("Hello
World"); to the user and then send the email?

I am aware that this can be done by writing a browser plugin, but I would like to avoid this if I can.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer : only with a browser plugin.

Contextual gadget will only show for incoming mail, not when composing a new mail.